# Sinon isn't calling the .done of Jquery.ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, gruntjs, qunit, sinon

I've used Qunit and Sinon,

```
self.urlRegex = /^(.*?)\/xxx\/xxxx\/xxxxx$/;
self.server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
self.server.respondWith(self.urlRegex, [200, {"Content-Type":"application/json"}, JSON.stringify(list)]);
sinon.spy(jQuery, "ajax");
$.ajax( {
    type : "GET", 
    url : "/xxx/xxxx/xxxxx", 
    dataType : "json"
})
.done(function (data) {
    self.names = data.data;
});

self.server.respond();
self.server.restore();
jQuery.ajax.restore();
```

Now If I try to get the names value it returns undefined instead of list.data, looks like the done part is not happening.

Any way to get the value and set in the names?

Comment: And how/where do you try to call it? Ajax is async, right?!

Comment: @A.Wolff 
    self.server.respond();

Comment: I don't know `sinon` but ajax is async by default, so you are calling `self.server.respond();` before ajax request is done

Comment: @A.Wolff Sinon is a spy agent that mocks the ajax call. repond() in sinon Causes all queued asynchronous requests to receive a response.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the URL. it had some special char's added due to which the .fail() was called instead of .done()